# Passing a List of objects between Dart and JavaScript — convert List<dynamic> to List<GeocodeResult>

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-js-interop

I'm trying to access the [Google Maps Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) JavaScript API from Dart.

I have this code, which uses the [js package](https://pub.dev/packages/js) to translate to Dart:

```
@JS('google.maps')
library google_maps;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS()
class Geocoder {
  external Geocoder();
  external geocode(GeocodeOptions options, void Function(List<GeocodeResult> results, String status) callback);
}

@JS()
@anonymous
class GeocodeResult {
  // ...
}
```

... And I'm calling it from my application like this:

```
geocoder.geocode(
  GeocodeOptions(
    address: address,
    region: region,
  ),
  allowInterop((results, status) {
    // ???
  }),
);
```

The problem is with the type of the `results` list in the callback function:

```
void Function(List<GeocodeResult> results, String status)
```

With the type set to `GeocodeResult`, I get an error:

> Expected a value of type `List<GeocodeResult>` but got one of type `List<dynamic>`

But if I change the type to `dynamic`, then my callback function in dart receives a `List<NativeJavaScriptObject>`.

I don't know what to do with a `NativeJavascriptObject`!

- it's not a `Map`, so I can't use square brackets — `result['geometry']`
- if I try to use `List.cast<GeocodeResult>()` then I get an error: *dart.notNull() is not a Function*
- it's a dart object, so I can't just access arbitrary properties using dot notation — `result.geometry`

Any and all suggestions welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've got it working by converting to JSON in JavaScript and then parsing the JSON into a `Map` in dart:

```
geocoder.geocode(
  GeocodeOptions(
    address: address,
    region: region,
  ),
  allowInterop((results, status) {
    final list = List<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    results.forEach((jsObject) {
      //Convert NativeJavascriptObject to Map by encoding and decoding JSON
      final json = stringify(jsObject);
      final map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(json));
      list.add(map);
    });
  }),
);
```

This uses `stringify()`, below, which calls `JSON.stringify()` from JavaScript.

```
@JS('JSON.stringify')
external String stringify(Object obj);
```

Comment: So the last bit of code with the two lines.. where does that go exactly?

Comment: Somewhere within the same file (with `@JS() library...` at the top) in the top-level scope

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution that doesn't require an intermediate conversion to string, this iteratively builds a dart map and offers a similar result.

```dart
static Map<String,dynamic> jsToJson(Object js) => objectKeys(js)
  .whereType<String>()
  .fold({}, (value, element) => value..[element] = getProperty(js, element));
```